# Select most frequently occurring records using two or more grouping columns

Tags: sql

I have a table which has no primary key and I can't add one - the relevant columns from it are:

```
Department   | Category  | 
-------------+-----------+
0001         | A         |
0002         | D         |
0003         | A         | 
0003         | A         |
0003         | C         |
0004         | B         |
```

I want to retrieve a single row for each `Department`, which gives me the department code and the `Category` which appears most frequently in the table, i.e.

```
Department   | Category  | 
-------------+-----------+
0001         | A         |
0002         | D         |
0003         | A         | 
0004         | B         |
```

What is the best way to achieve this?  My current attempt involves a `Count(Category)` in a subquery from which the `Max(CountofCategory)` is then taken, but including the `Category` field at this stage means too many rows at returned (since `GROUP BY` is applied at `Category` level as well as `Department`).  In the case of a tie, I'd just select the min/max of the category arbitrarily.  Ideally this should be database-agnostic, but is likely to run on either Oracle or MySQL.

Comment: You stated that you can't modify the table by adding a primary key, but can you create views on top of the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works in both Oracle and SQL Server, I believe is all standard SQL, from later standards:

```
with T_with_RN as
    (select Department
        , Category
        , row_number() over (partition by Department order by count(*) Desc) as RN
    from T
    group by Department, Category)
select Department, Category
from T_with_RN
where RN = 1
```

**EDIT** I don't know why I used the WITH, the solution is probably easier to read using an inline view:

```
select Department, Category
from (select Department
    , Category
    , row_number() over (partition by Department order by count(*) Desc) as RN
    from T
    group by Department, Category) T_with_RN
where RN = 1
```

**END EDIT**

Test cases:

```
create table T (
    Department varchar(10) null,
    Category varchar(10) null
);

-- Original test case
insert into T values ('0001', 'A');
insert into T values ('0002', 'D');
insert into T values ('0003', 'A');
insert into T values ('0003', 'A');
insert into T values ('0003', 'C');
insert into T values ('0004', 'B');
-- Null Test cases:
insert into T values (null, 'A');
insert into T values (null, 'B');
insert into T values (null, 'B');
insert into T values ('0005', null);
insert into T values ('0005', null);
insert into T values ('0005', 'X');
-- Tie Test case
insert into T values ('0006', 'O');
insert into T values ('0006', 'P');
```

Comment: The original question doesn't mention how to handle ties.  Your solution selects one of the tied rows, effectively at random.  I think it would be better to use RANK() instead of ROW_NUMBER(), as that returns all rows which tie for first place.

Comment: @APC: He does mention ties:  "In the case of a tie, I'd just select the min/max of the category arbitrarily." Which I took to mean he didn't care which of the tied categories was chosen. You are correct that rank() would return ties.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following as well. Window here returns the Categories ordered by their descending frequency of match against each Department. FIRST_VALUE() picks the first one from this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (department), 
  FIRST_VALUE(category) OVER
    (PARTITION BY department ORDER BY count(*) DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM T
GROUP BY department, category;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to clean this up if you are better with subqueries than I am, but in my testing this produced the result you want:

```
SELECT
  main.Department as Department,
  (SELECT 
     Category
   FROM yourtable
   WHERE Department=main.Department
   GROUP BY Category
   ORDER BY COUNT(Category) DESC
   LIMIT 1) AS Category
FROM yourtable main
GROUP BY main.Department
```

The trick is just to get the one row in the subquery to return the max value you want with the ORDER BY and the "LIMIT 1"

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way:

```
select department, stats_mode(category) from T ;
```

works great when only the most frequent value is needed, when you need 2nd, 3rd... most frequent you have to do the counting like above.